# Horizontal scrollview activated with button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to get the effect showed in the image below:

[image]

The blue box is supposed to be the `UIScrollView`. Once you launch the application what you see is button 1 and 2, but I want that when the user pushes button 1 for example, the scroll view moves horizontally to the left and shows Text Field 1 and 2 in the same position where the buttons were.

I guess the `UIScrollView` is the best way to do it and then implement in one of the buttons the code to make that transition (using Core Graphics?). If you have any better idea or a link with a tutorial with same effect would be great.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it (mostly) with Storyboard:

Make a UIView which will act as container for your buttons and textfields with **640 width**

[image: containerview]

Make sure the view is at positioned at **x: 0** then add the buttons, now make **x: -320** and add the textFields

[image: textfields]

Next link the container view to your code by **ctrl+dragging** it and name it (mine `bottomMenuView`)

[image: bottomMenuViewIBOutlet]

Now **cntr+drag** from your `button1` to your **.M** code for an `IBAction` (mine button1Method)

[image: buttonmethod]

And finally move the x coordinate to reposition the container view with this method body

[image: methodbody]

Comment: Pretty nice way to do it and very well explained! Thank you Michael I'll play a little bit more with your answer and see what else I can do.